# Theorems of Lebesgue integration theory which is useful for calculating integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

It is well known that fundamental theorem of calculus and residue theorem are very useful for calculating integral.

However I haven't heard such things in Lebesgue integration theory. Are there any such theorems? The ones only for particular measure spaces are ok.

**Edit**:"such" means "useful for calculating integral **value directly**". Some special concrete situations are also ok.

Comment: Of course. Do you know how to compute the Gaussian? (Change of variables!)

Comment: @Kezer Do you mean Gaussian integral(the value is \sqrt{\pi})?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: @Kezer Could it be Using Fubini's theorem as in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral?wprov=sfla1 ?

Comment: One possibility is by Fubini, yeah. Note that Fubini is part of measure theory! The most well known proof is by polar coordinates (the first proof sketched on wikipedia). That one uses change of variables.

Comment: @Kezer Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Tonelli and Fubini theorems are two of the most important results from measure theory to allow multi-dimensional integrals to be calculated over sets that aren't suitably elementary.

Furthermore, the Lesbegue Dominated Convergence Theorem shows up all the time to calculate limits and derivatives of intgrals.